# Firebase email link authentication with custom domain

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

The firebase documentation is a little vague on setting things up with a custom dynamic link domain.

In a react native app, I can successfully have a passwordless email authentication link sent to the user inbox.

```
My const actionCodeSettings = {
  url: 'https://xxxxxx.com/some-verify-email-redirect-web-page',
  // This must be true.
  handleCodeInApp: true,
  iOS: {
    bundleId: 'com.xxxxxx.xxxxxxapp',
  },
  android: {
    packageName: 'com.xxxxxx.xxxxxxapp',
    installApp: true,
    minimumVersion: '12',
  },
  dynamicLinkDomain: 'xxxxxx.com',
};
```

I already authorized my custom domain and was able to create and use dynamic links to the android app.
However, my custom dynamic link domain is `xxxxxx.com/app`. This means that my app is listening to the prefix `/app`:

```
"android": {
  "package": "com.xxxxxx.xxxxxxapp",
  "versionCode": 1,
  "googleServicesFile": "./firebase/google-services.json",
  "permissions": ["ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION", "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"],
  "intentFilters": [
    {
      "action": "VIEW",
      "data": [
        {
          "scheme": "https",
          "host": "xxxxxx.com",
          "pathPrefix": "/app"
        }
      ],
      "category": ["BROWSABLE", "DEFAULT"]
    }
  ]
},
```

The verification link I get looks like this: `https://xxxxxx.com?link=https://xxxxxx-app.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?apiKey...continueUrl%3Dhttps://xxxxxx.com/app/some-verify-email-redirect-web-page%26lang%3Den&apn=com.xxxxxx.xxxxxxapp&amv=12&ibi=com.xxxxxx.xxxxxxapp&ifl=https://xxxxxx-app.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?apiKey...signIn%26oobCode...continueUrl%3Dhttps://xxxxxx.com/app/...`

So I'm not surprised my app doesn't detect it as an app link because it's missing the `/app`

Interestingly enough, if I use the default `xxxxxx.page.link` domain for this purpose, then at least it tries to open some app, but of course cannot and redirects to the Play Store.

Do I need to create a dynamic link manually on Firebase to handle this custom domain verification link?

Do I need to add something to my intentFilters?

Any experts out there who can help with this? What am I missing?

Comment: Did you find a solution?